# RESTful API testing - no data being returned, just object id's

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm playing around with mongodb/node.js trying to test my database using insomnia.  When i make a POST request the array of objects is returned but it only contains the object id's.  The weird thing is, when i manually add data using mongo, all the data that was entered in that instance is returned correctly as JSON, but when added in insomnia, only the id's are returned.  What am i missing? Here is my post route:

```
router.post("/", function(req,res){
  var car = req.body.car;
  var newCar = new Car(car);
  newCar.save(function(err, car){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    else{
      res.redirect(302, "/cars");
    }
  })
})
```

and here is what is returned in insomnia:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "_id": "5842322dbb7039837fdec0b7",
            "car": "Ferrari",
            "top_speed": "200"
        },
        {
            "_id": "58423607bb7039837fdec0b8",
            "car": "Ford",
            "top_speed": "150"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5842384b65039e33bb436ef2",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "58423b2165039e33bb436ef3",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "58423b3fa7cb093588dd2c47",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "58423d8da7cb093588dd2c48",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

my syntax for the POST request is as follows:

```
    {
        "car": "Ford",
        "top_speed": "150"
    }
```

and the model, if it helps:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "car": String,
  "top_speed": String,
})

var Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);

module.exports = Car;
```

Comment: not clear bro u choose top speed 150 but there is some record with out top speed at bottom

Comment: @ adil thats the problem.  The data at the top of the array is complete (this is the data i entered into mongo on the terminal) and then the blank data at the bottom is where i sent the data through insomnia and postman.   if it helps i can add my model..

Comment: If I read your post correctly the value of `car` when it's passed into `new Car(car)` would be a string of `Ford` not an object. The mongoose model `Car` takes an object as an argument, not a string. You should just use `var car = req.body` to get the entire body object. Mongoose will parse the properties that match your schema and validate based on the schema settings. Since the string that you're passing in has no properties, no values are being applied to the new document.